# Angular5 custom tree component

Tags: tree, angular5

> How to create a custom tree component in angular 5.I am a beginner in angular.I have no idea.

[image]

**"+" Button create new node and "Add Route" Button create sub node. Each node contains two drop down to select values.**

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to recursively call a component. Here is a simple example:

**node.model.ts**

```js
export class Node {
  children: Node[];
  text: string;
}
```

**tree.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'tree',
  template: `<h1>Tree component</h1>
        <div *ngFor="let node of tree">
         <node [node]="node"></node>
        </div>
        <button (click)="addNodeTo()">add node</button>


  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  tree: Node[] = [];
  ngOnInit(){
    let firstNode = {
      children: [],
      text: 'first'
    }
    this.tree.push(firstNode);
  }

  addNodeTo(){
      let newNode = {
        children: [],
        text: 'newNode',
      }
      this.tree.push(newNode);
  }
```

and the **node.component.ts**, which is called recursively :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'node',
  template: `
    {{node.text}} <button (click)="addChildren(node)">Add children</button>
    <div *ngFor="let children of node.children">
      <node [node]='children'></node>
    </div>

  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class NodeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() node: Node;
  ngOnInit(){
  }

  addChildren(node: Node){
      let newNode = {
        children: [],
        text: node.text +  `'s child`
      }
      node.children.push(newNode);
  }
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eatv7m?embed=1&file=src/app/node.component.ts) without styles but you will understand the logic.

Comment: In my api response children are not array.

Comment: "flow":{  
"children":{  
   "2":{  
      "children":{},
      "data":{"id":"ggfg"},
   },
   "4":{  
      "children":{  
         "7":{  
            "children":{},
               "data":{"id":"effgfdv"},
         }
      },
      "data":{"id":"fgdfgdg"},
   }
},
"data":{"id":"fghhhj"},
},

Comment: Is any way to convert to json to array

Comment: Yes, you can do it front-end side, maybe using a recursive function too. You could have a look at [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10) for Objects/Arrays handling.

Comment: Can you help me to do the same with netsted node,  I am using nested JSON